# Set the page size in Jtable && razor application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jtable

I have included a new frame in my HTML-page, in this frame I have a `Jtable` .

I need to set the default pagesize to 4 to have the included view without scoller.

I made this changes:

```
        options: {
        paging: false,
        pageList: 'normal', //possible values: 'minimal', 'normal'
        pageSize: 4,
        pageSizes: [4, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500],
        pageSizeChangeArea: true,
        gotoPageArea: 'combobox', //possible values: 'textbox', 'combobox', 'none'

        messages: {
            pagingInfo: 'Showing {0}-{1} of {2}',
            pageSizeChangeLabel: 'Row count',
            gotoPageLabel: 'Go to page'
        }
    },
```

In `jquery.jtable.js` and `jquery.jtable.min.js`. But I get always **the page size = 10**.

So , I need to know

1. Why the modification that I made wasn't sufficient?
2. How can I fix page size to 4 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this question was asked a while ago but I came across this problem myself recently and figured out what was going on..

Basically, jtable stores your preference for row count in a cookie. So if you previously viewed the page with pageSize 10, that's stored and when you change the JavaScript to a different it still picks up the value of 10 and it looks like nothing has changed.

Clear your cookies and it should work for you with the new pageSize.